# Tablet PC/on-screen keyboard on secure desktop

Tags: winapi, uac, on-screen-keyboard, tablet-pc

When using the UAC dialog (which runs on a secure desktop) is used on a tablet PC, it provides the on-screen-keyboard for the password field (pretty much the same as the login screen). I think this is implemented in tabtip.exe.

Now I also use a secure desktop for a password prompt. In (sparse) pseudo code, this looks like:

```
hDesk = CreateDesktop("my random desktop name", NULL, 0, 0, CREATE_MENU|CREATE_WINDOW|READ_OBJECTS|WRITE_OBJECTS|SWITCH_DESKTOP);
CreateThread(SecureDesktopThread)
```

And in `SecureDesktopThread`:

```
...
SetThreadDesktop(hDesk);
SwitchDesktop(hDesk);
MyDialog dlg = new MyDialog();
dlg.ShowModal();
...
```

However, the table PC keyboard (IME?) is not available on the secure desktop, making it unuseable on a tablet PC.

How can the tablet pc/softkeyboard/IME be enabled?

As an example which keyboard I mean (not in a secure desktop because I can't capture screenshots there):

[image: screenshot of tablet pc keyboard]